How to get space in button .popover TextEditor?
When I press space on the keyboard in TextEditor, “parent button click” is printed in the application console, but the space is not put in the TextEditor. There are no such problems with other characters. How to get space in TextEditor in that case?
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var showPopoverComment = false
    
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            print("parent button click")
        }) {
            VStack {
                Button("child button", action: {showPopoverComment = true})
                    .popover(isPresented: $showPopoverComment) {
                        EditCommentView()
                            .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                    }
                // other views ...
            }
        }.buttonStyle(.plain)
    }
}

struct EditCommentView: View {
    @State var comment: String = ""
    var body: some View {
        TextEditor(text: $comment)
    }
}



Move the .popover outside the parent Button.
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var showPopoverComment = false
    
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            print("parent button click")
        }) {
            VStack {
                Button("child button", action: {showPopoverComment = true})
                // other views ...
            }
        }.buttonStyle(.plain)
        
        .popover(isPresented: $showPopoverComment) {  // <--- here
            EditCommentView()
                .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
        }
    }
}

